# Пресная жидкость

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, терминология, смысл

В одной из околонаучных передач позвучало такое предложение:
**Миллионы людей будут мигрировать в поисках пресной жидкости.**

(Разговор шел об экологической катастрофе, об озере Байкал, о загрязнении водоёмов.)

*Пресная жидкость* — грамотно ли так говорить по отношению к питьевой воде?

Comment: Что тут неграмотного? И что, собственно, смущает? Бывает солёная жидкость, бывает кислая, горькая... и бывает пресная.

Answer (score 2):

В данном контексте сочетание вызывает вопросы. Такое ощущение, что автор хотел щегольнуть изысканной формулировкой, но попал впросак. Зачем заменять очевидное "вода" синонимичным (в данных условиях) "жидкость"?

Вообще я нашел лишь один не режущий слух пример этого "пресная жидкость", причем далеко не бесспорный. Там речь шла о *внутриклеточной* "пресной жидкости". Тоже вода, но как бы "не совсем вода".

Answer (score 1):

**Пресная жидкость — грамотно ли так говорить по отношению к питьевой воде?**

Пресная <s>жидкость</s> вода — более широкое понятие, чем питьевая вода. Могу привести несколько примеров.
1. Ту воду, которая течёт у Вас дома из "горячего крана", Вы вряд ли назовёте питьевой. При этом она вполне может быть пресной и миллионы людей в мире предпочли бы эту воду воде из ближайшей лужи (хотя даже с лужами им нужна [помощь благотворительных организаций](http://www.priroda.su/item/894)).
2. Хорошо бы услышать более широкий и точный контекст сказанного в передаче. Так, Вы могли сконцентрироваться на питьевой воде, а в передаче могла идти речь в том числе об орошении полей и огородов, о животноводстве и т.п. Эти проблемы нельзя решить только изобретением специальных трубочек для питья воды из луж (см. ссылку выше).

**Дополнение.**
Да, слово "жидкость" действительно не к месту. Я отредактировал ответ в терминах "пресной воды".

Comment: Ваша ссылка заставляет в очередной раз задуматься — мы часто не ценим то, к чему привыкли.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, сочетание "пресная жидкость" может иметь смысл. Например, жидкое лекарство, которое водой не назовешь, может быть пресным на вкус.
Вот пример образного употребления этого выражения:

> Вкрапления горьковцев казались везде очень незначительными, преобладание куряжан бросалось в глаза, и нужно было опасаться, что начнет преобладать и стиль их работы, тем более, что среди горьковцев было очень много новеньких, да и некоторые старики, растворившись в куряжской **пресной жидкости**, грозили просто исчезнуть как активная сила. [А. С. Макаренко. Педагогическая поэма. Часть 3 (1935)]

Но в вашем предложении люди будут мигрировать в поисках именно воды, поэтому употребление слова *жидкость* там стилистически неверно, а говоря простым языком, режет слух.

Comment: Вот и я во время передачи (что-то делала - просто слушала) "зациклилась", даже записала.